# Laravel custom format lists from Eloquent Collection to Form::select

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I have entity cities. Usually I can use `City::lists("name", "id")` to show in html Form::select.

There is need to show country code also in the form next to city name. Does any of the Eloquent Collection metods support it is recommended to use foreach and build the array manually?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can make use of [attribute accessors](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators) here. Add this to your model:

```
public function getNameWithCountryCodeAttribute(){
    return $this->attributes['name'] . ' ' . $this->attributes['country_code'];
}
```

And then use that dynamic attribute in `lists()`. Note that you have to fetch the collection first, so you actually call `lists()` on the collection and not the query builder.

```
City::all()->lists('nameWithCountryCode', 'id')
```

To reduce the queried columns to the minimum needed:

```
City::get(['id', 'name', 'code'])->lists('nameWithCountryCode', 'id')
```

Comment: +1 I would just select the columns needed: `City::get(['id', 'name', 'code'])->lists('nameWithCountryCode', 'id')`